# Random walk in Python + turtle

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

I decided to implement a random walk.

### The rules

The rules are easy, an object is moved in the direction dictated by random or pseudo-random numbers. 
If you want to read more about it, [see the Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk).

### A simple example

Let's say we decide:

- `1 = "Go right"`
- `2 = "Go down"`
- `3 = "Go left"`
- `4 = "Go up"`

We then generate the random or pseudo-random sequence: `3,1,4,1`.
And we convert it to directions:

- Left
- Right
- Up
- Right

we obtain the following:

[image]

### A more complex example

Runnning my code with:

- `step_size = 15`
- `step_number = 1000`

Generated the following walk:

[image: Random walk]

Running the code with the exact same parameters may yield completely different results because pseudo-random numbers are used.

---

I think my code is well written and fully Pep8 compliant, two things bother me

1. - I define many `go_<direction>` methods to go to absolute directions, I could have done something like:

     turn_of_random_deegres()
     turtle.forward(step)

   But it looked cleaner to me, albeit a little longer, to define absolute moving.
2. - The `go_<direction>` methods change between logo and standard edition. ([Control-Find setheading in this doc-page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading))

---

### The code

```
import turtle
import random

def go_right(step):
     turtle.setheading(0)
     turtle.forward(step)

def go_up(step):
     turtle.setheading(90)
     turtle.forward(step)


def go_left(step):
     turtle.setheading(180)
     turtle.forward(step)

def go_down(step):
     turtle.setheading(270)
     turtle.forward(step)

def make_random_walk(step_size, step_number):
    move_dict = {1: go_up,
                 2: go_right,
                 3: go_left,
                 4: go_down
                 }
    for _ in range(step_number):
        move_in_a_direction = move_dict[random.randint(1, 4)]
        move_in_a_direction(step_size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed("fastest")
    make_random_walk(15, 1000)
```

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks nice and seems to be fully PEP 8 compliant indeed. The fact that you have 1 blank line between functions except in one place where you have 2 puzzles me a bit but that's not a huge issue.

You can actually make your code much easier. Here are a individual steps, you'll find the final code at the end.

- Notice that you call `turtle.forward(step)` in each `go_somewhere` function. You might as well remove this and put it once and for all after your call to `move_in_a_direction(step_size)`. Now, the `go_somewhere` function doesn't need to be given a `step` anymore.
- Notice that the different function `go_somewhere` are just a call to `setheading` with a custom parameter. You could transform `move_dict` to map numbers to angles and call `turtle.setheading(move_dict[random.randint(1, 4))`.
- Notice that your map is just converting 1 into 0, 2 into 90, 3 into 180, 4 into 270. This can be substitued with a simple operation : remove 1 then multiply by 90. You now have `turtle.setheading((random.randint(1, 4) - 1) * 90)`.
- Notice that generating an integer in [0, 1, 2, 3] makes things even easier as you don't need to remove 1.

Here's the corresponding code :

```
def make_random_walk(step_size, step_number):
    for _ in range(step_number):
        turtle.setheading(90 * random.randint(0, 3))
        turtle.forward(step_size)
```

Answer (score 5):

All of the `go_*` functions are implemented with the same code. The only difference is the value passed to `setheading()`. You could create one common implementation and replace them with calls to that function.

```
def go(step, heading):
     turtle.setheading(heading)
     turtle.forward(step)

def go_down(step):
     go(step, 270)
```

Extracting repeated code will ensure that, if a bug exists in the common code, you won't have to remember to fix it in all the locations. It can also lead to a smaller overall code size. With this code the benefit is minimal, but as code gets more complex it will help a lot.

---

Instead of creating a dictionary and randomly indexing a specific value, you can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.choice). It will do the work to select a random element.

```
move_options = (go_up, go_right, go_left, go_down)
for _ in range(step_number):
    move_in_a_direction = random.choice(move_options)
    move_in_a_direction(step_size)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that you can simplify the simulation like this without losing any clarity:

```
import turtle
import random

def go(heading, step_size):
    turtle.setheading(heading)
    turtle.forward(step_size)

def random_walk(step_size, steps):
    # Assumes turtle.mode('standard')
    DIRECTIONS = (EAST, NORTH, WEST, SOUTH) = (0, 90, 180, 270)
    for _ in range(steps):
        go(random.choice(DIRECTIONS), step_size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    random_walk(15, 1000)
```

I've changed the terminology from right/left to east/west, since the former could be misinterpreted as a relative turn rather than an absolute heading.  In any case, the designations are entirely optional.

The use of a dict is not ideal.  You end up hard-coding 1–4 twice.

Be consistent with your parameter names.  `step_size` is more descriptive than `step`, so use it for all of the functions.  `step_number` sounds like the *n*<sup>th</sup> step to me, and would be slightly better named `steps`.